# C3 chart width is not correct in materialize modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js, materialize

I my application I am using c3 chart with materializecss design. In that for full screen chart feature, I am trying to construct c3 chart in a materialize modal. Here I can able to generate the chart dynamically. But what the problem is chart's width is not correct until I resize the window. It is appearing in a scrollable modal like this.

[Modal with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh3xw.png)

But when I drag inspect element screen, chart is displaying correctly. I used $(window).trigger('resize'); also. But still not working.

Please help me to achieve this.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="fullScreenMdl" class="modal">
    <button class="modal-close btn-flat">X</button>
    <div class="modal-content" >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div id="fullScreenMdlContent" style="max-width:100%;margin:0 auto;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300], ]
    }
});
$("#fullScreenMdl").openModal();
$(window).trigger('resize');
```